# Single processes tree with exec

Tags: c, linux

I have to write a script creating processes tree using `fork()` function. Then I need to use the `exec()` function inside the script, to generate only ONE processes tree, with `pstree -c` command.

Ok, so I created processes tree, that's not a problem, let's say:

```
int main() {
   int pid1, pid2;
   if(pid1 = fork()) {
      printf("%d", pid1);
   } else if (pid2 = fork()) {
      printf("%d", pid2);
   } else {
      printf("%s", "parent process");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But how do I use exec function to invoke pstree -c command? And how can I show only one specific tree?

```
execl("/bin/pstree -c", "pstree -c", 0, 0);
```

I tried with `/bin/`, without it...nothing works, the tree is not displayed when I run the script.

And it would display the whole tree anyways, not just the forks I used.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `execl`, each command argument should be a separate argument to the function. The first argument should be the path to the program you want to exec; there's no `-c` in the program name, that's an argument. If you just want to show the current process tree, you need to add a PID argument.

```
char pid[10];
sprintf(pid, "%d", getpid());

execl("/bin/pstree", "pstree", "-c", pid, (char*)0);
```